# Conflicting key values when running all Unit test with SQLite inMemory database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5 project, where I'm unit testing on a SQLite database. When I run the tests individually all tests are passing, but when I run all the tests at once, I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'Contact' **cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked**. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

> Stack Trace: [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey
> key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate) [xUnit.net
> 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry
> entry) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry
> entry) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
> oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean
> modifyProperties) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
> entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties,
> Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1
> node) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry
> rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState
> storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
> [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState) [xUnit.net 00:00:03.06]            at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Add(TEntity
> entity)

In each unit test, I'm using the 'using' statement, so the database context should be disposed as I understand.

I have a TestBase class:

```
using System;
using Project.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Project.Connections.Test
{
    public class TestBase
    {
        private bool useSqlite;

        public DataContext GetDbContext()
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
            if (useSqlite)
            {
                // Use Sqlite DB.
                builder.UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:", x => { });
            }
            else
            {
                // Use In-Memory DB.
                builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }

            var dbContext = new DataContext(builder.Options);
            if (useSqlite)
            {
                // SQLite needs to open connection to the DB.
                // Not required for in-memory-database and MS SQL.
                dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
            }

            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            TestData.Seed(dbContext);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return dbContext;
        }

        public void UseSqlite()
        {
            useSqlite = true;
        }
    }
}
```

One of the objects that I'm seeding is causing the problem. Note that the customer of the project contains a contacts and addresses list, and the project object itself has one of the customer's contact and address:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Project.Data.Customers;
using Project.Data.Projects;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Project.Data
{
    public class TestData
    {
        public static void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            // Other data...
            CreateProjects(context);
        }

        private static void CreateProjects(DataContext context)
        {
            var project1 = new Project()
            {
                Name = "Lorem",
                ProjectNumber = "2020/10/0001",
                DeadLine = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
                Customer = microsoft,
                State = ProjectState.Accepted,
                Contact = microsoft.Contacts.First(),
                DeliveryAddress = microsoft.DeliveryAddresses.First(),
                EndSize = new Size()
                {
                    Height = 300,
                    Width = 2000,
                },
            };

            context.Projects.Add(project1);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // Other project objects...
        }

        private static Customer microsoft = new Customer
        {
            IsCompany = true,
            CompanyName = "Microsoft",
            Contacts = new List<Contact>()
            {
                new Contact
                {
                    FirstName = "Bill",
                    LastName = "Gates",
                    PhoneNumber = "+16506815000",
                    Email = "bill.gates@microsoft.com",
                    Other = "CEO, in case of emergency :)",
                }
            },
            DeliveryAddresses = new List<Address>()
            {
                new Address
                {
                     Country = "USA",
                     ZipCode = "WS 98052-6399",
                     City = "Redmond",
                     Street = "One Microsoft Way",
                     Other = "Microsoft HQ"
                },
                new Address
                {
                     Country = "Norway",
                     ZipCode = "0194",
                     City = "Oslo",
                     Street = "Dronning Eufemias gate 71",
                     Other = "Microsoft Norway"
                }
            }
        
        };
    }
}
```

And this is how my unit test looks like:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Project.Connections.Services.Projects;
using Project.Data.Customers;
using Project.Data.Projects;
using Project.Data.Projects.Dtos;
using Xunit;

namespace Project.Connections.Test
{
    public class ProjectServiceTests : TestBase
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetAll_ShouldReturn()
        {
            UseSqlite();

            using (var context = GetDbContext())
            {
                var ProjectService = new ProjectService(context);

                var result = await ProjectService.GetAll();

                Assert.Equal(3, result.Count()); // I made 3 dummy projects originally
            }
        }

    // Other tests...
```

I've checked many articles in the last couple of days, but I couldn't figure out what causes the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @CedricArnould Not really, I just made new objects instead of referencing, since it was dummy data. However I learned how EF can set to not track an object. Ex.: insted of `microsoft.Contacts.First();` try `microsoft.Contacts.AsNoTacking().First();` Maybe that can help :)

Comment: The thing is I want to delete the item from DB, so I need to keep the tracking (from my understanding). I resolve by doing a new Action in the API to delete it, not exactly what I wanted, but It works.